# How do I write a function that uses a constant list of pair of words without using a file?

Tags: string, list

In C++, I have a constant list of pairs of words and I need a function such that if the given word is found in one of the columns it must return the corresponding word from the other column. How do I do that properly and without using a file? I do not have a type "constlist" or anything; It is a constant list which does not change ever, I just need the program to store it inside it, not in a file. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
findWord w xs = head [s | (p, q) <- xs, s <- if p == w then [q] else if q == w then [p] else []]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some Scala.

```
val words = """
  one    two
  three  four
  five   six
"""

def find(x: String): Option[String] = 
  words.trim.lines.
    map(line => line.trim.split("\\s+")).
    find(pair => pair.contains(x)).
    map(pair => pair((pair.indexOf(x)+1) % 2))

find("three") // Some(four)
find("six")   // Some(five)
find("seven") // None
```